# git doesn't work anymore after moving user home to external drive

Tags: user-account, homebrew, git

I've moved my users home directory from `/Users/romeovs` to `/Volumes/DATA/home` and ever since I get a git error.

Whenever I use `git clone` or `git init` it replies:

```
 fatal: Failed to expand user dir in: '~git/init'
```

has anyone had this problem?
I tried reinstalling `git` from `hombrew` but that didn't fix it (I am using the homebrew installed git from `/usr/local/Cellar`)

Comment: Did you just move the directory?

Comment: yes  I copied all the files and then went into 'System Preferences > Users and Groups > [username] > Advanced Options...' and changed the *Home Directory* to match this. Then I did `sudo rm -r /Users/username` to remove old userdir.

Comment: What does `cd ~` result to in the shell? Also why did you move your entire home directory to an external volume? That probably is a bad idea to start with.

Comment: `cd ~` works perfectly fine. as does the rest of my computer / shell.

Comment: Maybe a wrong configuration directive? `git config -l`

Comment: 1. Did you check all you permissions? Permissions of files and folders can change when you copy them. 2. Did you check that any config paths are hardwired to your old directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed a faulty configuration directive:

```
[init]
     templatedir=~git/init
```

which I accidently copied from another machine, without copying the template directory as well.